# Finding min & max value from column one column and it's corresponding value from another

Tags: awk

This is my sample text file

```
[s]            [K]        
1              900
2              100 
3              200
8              1000
1              80
55             12
6              90000
5              1
```

I need to find the max value in column 2 and find the corresponding value in column 1, then subtracting the value from all elements of column 1.

My desired output is like this

```
[s]            [K]        
-5              900
-4              100 
-3              200
2              1000
-5              80
49             12
0              90000
-1              1
```

This is my snippet

```
awk 'function abs(x) {return x<0?-x:x}
FNR==1  { $1=$1; print; next }
{if(max<$2){max=$2;line=$1}}{print $1-line "\t"$2}' test.txt
```

Somehow this is not giving me correct result. 
I also want the same thing for minimum value in column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR==1 { next }
NR==2 { maxVal = $2 }
NR==FNR {
    if ($2 >= maxVal) {
        maxSth = $1
        maxVal = $2
    }
    next
}
{ print (FNR>1 ? ($1 - maxSth) : $1) , $2 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
[s]     [K]
-5      900
-4      100
-3      200
2       1000
-5      80
49      12
0       90000
-1      1
```

Comment: Great! But I don't understand why someone is continuously down voting every answer?

Comment: There are idiots out there who enjoy doing that. Don't worry about it, just upvote every answer to compensate when you notice it happening as I'm about to do.

Comment: Serial up or down voting is often caught by scripts running every night, and reversed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do two passes over your data to first find the minimum and maximum values, and then to do your calculations:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
     FNR == NR { if (FNR > 1 && (min == "" || $2 < min)) { min = $2; minval = $1 }
                 if (FNR > 1 && (max == "" || $2 > max)) { max = $2; maxval = $1 }
                 next }
     FNR == 1 { print "[s (-max)]", "[s (-min)]", "[K]"; next }
              { print $1 - maxval, $1 - minval, $2 }' file file
```

For the given data, this would produce

```
[s (-max)]      [s (-min)]      [K]
-5      -4      900
-4      -3      100
-3      -2      200
2       3       1000
-5      -4      80
49      50      12
0       1       90000
-1      0       1
```

The `awk` code have four blocks, and we pass the input file to it *twice*.  The first block (`BEGIN`) simply sets the output field separator to a tab character.

The second block (`FNR == NR`) will execute for each line of during the first pass over the file and keeps track of the maximum and minimum values in the 2nd column (`max` and `min`) and the corresponding values in the 1st column (`maxval` and `minval`), updating them as needed.  At the end of this block, `next` is used to skip the rest of the script for the current input.

`NR` is the ordinal number for the current record (the "line number") overall, while `FNR` is the same number for the current file.  `NR` will be the same as `FNR` only for the first pass over the input file.

The third block (`FNR == 1`) would be executed when having just read the first line from the second pass over the file.  It simply prints out a heading.  We're going to calculate both the subtraction of the `minval` and `maxval` values from the 1st column's value, so we add a new column header.

The final block is unconditional and would execute for the 2nd line onwards in the 2nd pass through the file and does the actual computation and output of the data.

You can get slightly prettier output by passing the output through `column -s $'\t' -t`:

```
[s (-max)]  [s (-min)]  [K]
-5          -4          900
-4          -3          100
-3          -2          200
2           3           1000
-5          -4          80
49          50          12
0           1           90000
-1          0           1
```

Comment: +1 for the explicated code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this? *note the processing file twice.*

```
awk 'NR==FNR && NR>1 { max_col2=( max_col2>$2?max_col2:$2 ); max[$2]=$1;  
                       min_col1=( min_col1>$1?min_col1:$1 ); min[$1]=$2; }
     NR!=FNR && FNR>1{ print $1-max[max_col2], $2-min[min_col1]; }' OFS='\t' infile infile
-5      888
-4      88
-3      188
2       988
-5      68
49      0
0       89988
-1      -11
```